# Query set in switch statement not executing

Tags: c#

I am trying to execute the two queries set within the switch statement, but neither appear to be updating the database:

```
switch (status) {
    case "Trade Rejected":
        query = "UPDATE booking " +
            "SET status=@status " +
            "WHERE (id=@job_offer_id AND id=@job_received_id);" +
            "UPDATE trade " +
            "SET job_received_id=0 " +
            "WHERE id=@id";
        break;

    case "Trade Accepted":
        query = "UPDATE booking " +
            "SET status=@status " +
            "WHERE (id=@job_offer_id AND id=@job_received_id);";
        query += "UPDATE booking AS offer " +
            "JOIN booking AS received " +
            "SET offer.operator_id = received.operator_id, received.operator_id = offer.operator_id " +
            "WHERE offer.id=@job_offer_id and received.id=@job_received_id";
        break;
};
```

I think that the code is being set in the switch statement, but not being executed past that. What would be the best way of handling this issue. Should I revert back to using an if else statement?

```
if (jobList.Count <= 0) return;
foreach(JobComponent.JobList job in jobList) {
    string[] statusArray = {
        "Trade Accepted", "Trade Rejected"
    };
    var status = statusArray[Rnd.Next(statusArray.Length)];

    switch (status) {
        case "Trade Rejected":
            query = "UPDATE booking " +
                "SET status=@status " +
                "WHERE (id=@job_offer_id AND id=@job_received_id);" +
                "UPDATE trade " +
                "SET job_received_id=0 " +
                "WHERE id=@id";
            break;

        case "Trade Accepted":
            query = "UPDATE booking " +
                "SET status=@status " +
                "WHERE (id=@job_offer_id AND id=@job_received_id);";
            query += "UPDATE booking AS offer " +
                "JOIN booking AS received " +
                "SET offer.operator_id = received.operator_id, received.operator_id = offer.operator_id " +
                "WHERE offer.id=@job_offer_id and received.id=@job_received_id";
            break;
    };

    using(var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, DbObject.Connection)) {
        if (DbObject.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open) {
            DbObject.OpenConnection();
        }
        try {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@id"), job.JobTradeId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@job_offer_id"), job.JobOfferId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@job_received_id"), job.JobReceivedId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(("@status"), status);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError(ex.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
    DbObject.CloseConnection();
}
```

Comment: Hit F5 to run your application. If you mean something else, please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) again.

Comment: Which query? Not clear what you are asking? Which query is failing to execute? Is your random call actually bringing back the query you expect? Which part is ACTUALLY failing here? Is it your logic?

Comment: I've updated the question with more details

Comment: Add a default clause and log + return in it. You will eliminate the possibility that you're just not executing anything, because query is empty...

Comment: Learn to debug. Set breakpoints and step through your code. Also check what your `ErrorHandlingComponent.LogError()` is doing.

Comment: As @Gerino points out, it's possible that query isn't being set because neither of your case conditions are true. You could also check this by adding a default to the bottom with another update query. For that matter, you need to check that there's anything in JobList so that the foreach loop will execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out - there was an issue with the SQL query:

```
                 query = "UPDATE booking " +
                         "SET status=@status " +
                         "WHERE (id=@job_offer_id AND id=@job_received_id);"
```

should be

```
                    query = "UPDATE booking " +
                            "SET status=@status " +
                            "WHERE id=@job_offer_id;" +

                            "UPDATE booking " +
                            "SET status=@status " +
                            "WHERE id=@job_received_id;";
```

or as suggested by CodeCaster:

`WHERE (id=@job_offer_id OR id=@job_received_id);`

Comment: Or, you know, `WHERE (id=@job_offer_id OR id=@job_received_id);` if you want both records to get the same status.

Comment: So much more better!